# Ajax post to php serverside code

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is home work and I was given some Ajax javascript code I need to modify. I am having trouble figuring out the syntax of some of the code.

Here is the provided code and I am suppose to write the php serverside code

```
function submit_login() {
    if( document.form.loggedIn.checked ) return
    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.onreadystatechange = respond_login
    request.open("POST", "AjaxController.php", true /* asynchronous? */ )
    request.send( "action=login&password=" + postEscape( document.form.pwd.value ) +
                    "&username=" + postEscape( document.form.user.value ))
    document.form.pwd.value = ""
    document.form.user.value = ""
}
```

I am confused on how to write the server side part for the POST. Normally I would write something like this:

```
$action = $_POST['"action=login&password="];
```

However I am confused as how to write the above line since two variable are passed through the send. I think I need to parse it but I still find this line confusing as to whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the server side you fetch the values with 3 statements:

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```